# What is the reference for this Ember.js guides setupController multiple models with arraycontroller

Tags: ember.js

Presently I am going though every page and snippit of code in the Ember.js Guides and building a small sample app. Some I have gotten stuck on for a bit but solved. This one however befuddles me.

At http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/
It's also here but does not use the .get('songs") http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-a-single-model-with-objectcontroller/

```
App.SongsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, playlist) {
    controller.set('model', playlist.get('songs'));
  }
});
```

I don't know what playlist.get('songs') is referencing. I assume it's a model object array inner object but I am wrong obviously. But since the example code at their site does not have mock stub data to work from I am just guessing from all of my tests.

The code provided here has some commented out bits to see what I was testing.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="songs">
    <h1>Playlist</h1>
    <ul>
      {{#each}}
        <li>{{name}} by {{artist}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="playlist">
    <h3>Playlist: </h3>
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0-rc.3/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.0.0-rc.6/ember.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('songs');
  this.resource('playlist');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('songs');
  }
});

// App.SongsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
//   setupController: function(controller, model) {
//     controller.set('model', model);
//   },
//   model: function () {
//     // return songs;
//     return playlist.songs;
//   }
// });

App.SongsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  playlist: function() {
    var playlist = { songs: [{fish: "fish"}, {fish: "fish"}] };
    return playlist;
  }.property(),

  setupController: function(controller, playlist) {
    controller.set('model', playlist.get('songs'));
  }
});

App.PlaylistRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
  },
  model: function () {
    return playlist;
  }
});

App.SongsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

var songs = {
  duration: 777,
  name: 'Ember',
  artist: 'Jimmy Smith',
};

var playlist = {
  songs: [
    {
      id: 1,
      duration: 777,
      name: 'Ember',
      artist: 'Jimmy Smith',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      duration: 888,
      name: 'jQuery',
      artist: 'Hyper Cat',
    }
  ]
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this link (http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/) is a little confusing.  They are assuming that a model relationship is there, but they are not showing it.

They are assuming that there is something like this :

```
App.Playlist = DS.Model.extend({
  name : DS.attr('string'),
  songs : DS.hasMany('song',{async:true})
});

App.Song = DS.Model.extend({
  name : DS.attr('string')
});
```

And then generally what you'd want to do is to pull the collection from the `model` in `setupController`, and then set that as `content` on a nested controller that has been `need`ed by the main controller.

```
App.PlaylistRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController : function(controller,model){
    this._super(controller,model);
    this.controllerFor('songs').set('content',model.get('songs'));
  }
});

App.PlaylistController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs : ['songs']
});
```

And then since you're using `ArrayController` for the collection, you have built in sorting if you define the `sortProperties` and `sortAscending` properties.

```
App.SongsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties : ['name'],
  sortAscending : true
});
```

Here's a JSBin showing the general idea, using the `FixtureAdapter`.

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1073/edit

Comment: Yikes! Hmmm thats like a level curve of 1, 2, skip a few … 24! Let me tinker with this and then i'll select it as solved, thank you very much for the answer. I have been trying to be very strict and use the snippits provided without changing them the justify that I am doing things correctly even though their docs need some work.